# postgres password less connection not working from shell script

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

I have made required entries in .pgpass file with file permission set to 0600.

I am able to connect to db form shell command line without giving the password.

But when I run a shell script which internally queries postgres, it asks to enter password.

I am not able to figure out what could be wrong.

Here is a sample shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $1
psql -h $DBHOST -d $DBNAME -U $DBUSER << EOF
        select * from students limit 10;
EOF
```

All values for DBHOST, DBNAME and DBUSER are coming fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind.

I made a stupid mistake. I had edited config file on windows. So it had added crlf at the end of every line. So even though it was not visible it was being used when connecting to postgres.

So in command line
this worked.

```
psql -h 192.168.1.45 -d somedbname -U $somedbuse
```

But this did not. (after sourcing config file)

```
psql -h $DBHOST -d $DBNAME -U $DBUSER
```